# Print a jsonObject in a certain order

Tags: java, json, gson

Is it possible to print a jsonObject in a certain order?
This is what I have

```
import NPC.NPCHandler;
import NPC.NPCDrops;
import com.google.gson.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileWriter;

/**
 * @author Ruud.
 */
public class Main {

    public static NPCDrops npcDrops = new NPCDrops();
    public static NPCHandler npcHandler = new NPCHandler();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*for (int i = 1; i < npcs.length; i++)
            System.out.println(npcs[i].absX);*/
        JSONObject NPCDefinition = new JSONObject();
        NPCDefinition.put("New", "Tester");
        NPCDefinition.put("B", "Test");
        NPCDefinition.put("A", "Test");
        NPCDefinition.put("Test", "Tester");
        JSONArray NPCDefinitions = new JSONArray();
        NPCDefinitions.add(0, NPCDefinition);
        //NPCDefinitions.add(1, NPCDefinition);
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("./Json/NPCDefinitions.json")) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement je = jp.parse(NPCDefinitions.toJSONString());
            String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
            System.out.println(prettyJsonString);
            //file.write(prettyJsonString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it returns

```
[
  {
    "New": "Tester",
    "A": "Test",
    "B": "Test",
    "Test": "Tester"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to return it like the way it was put into the object?
I want this, because I am converting an NPC system in a game to a new better system using JSON, but I want the order to be in a human-logical way, like

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Hans",
    "examine": "Servant of the Duke of Lumbridge.",
    "combat": 0,
    "size": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Man",
    "examine": "One of many citizens.",
    "combat": 2,
    "drops": [
      {
        "id": 995,
        "amount": "1000",
        "chance": 0.50
      },
      {
        "id": 4151,
        "amount": "1",
        "chance": 1
      }
    ],
    "size": 1
  }
]
```

I didn't test it yet with these variables, but I am sure it will mess up the order too, so I want to know if there is a way to keep this order. I know this isn't possible with JSONObject, because it is an unordered list or something, but this can't be achieved in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON objects are unordered K/V sets, but it does not mean that strict order is required, therefore it can be fully implementation driven.

What you're missing here is mixing two different libraries: JSON Simple and Gson. I have never worked with JSON Simple before, but even a quick look to that library would reveal that its `org.json.simple.JSONObject` extends raw `HashMap` which order may differ in different JRE versions. Unlike `org.json.simple.JSONObject`, Gson's native `com.google.gson.JsonObject` preserves the insertion order (see more at [JsonObject implementation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java) -- just because it's implemented this way). The same mixing story goes to `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and `com.google.gson.JsonArray`. So, the easiest solution is just getting rid of JSON Simple in favor of not mixing two different libraries, and just using Gson facilities, like this:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final JsonObject npcDefinition = new JsonObject();
    npcDefinition.addProperty("New", "Tester");
    npcDefinition.addProperty("B", "Test");
    npcDefinition.addProperty("A", "Test");
    npcDefinition.addProperty("Test", "Tester");
    final JsonArray npcDefinitions = new JsonArray();
    npcDefinitions.add(npcDefinition);
    final String json = gson.toJson(npcDefinitions);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Also note, that no `toString()` invocation is necessary (it may be really expensive due to in-memory string allocations) here because Gson works with its `JsonElement` sub-classes just perfect. Thus, the original order is preserved:

```
[
  {
    "New": "Tester",
    "B": "Test",
    "A": "Test",
    "Test": "Tester"
  }
]
```

Since the objects are meant to be unordered, you should not really rely even on this implementation (I'm using Gson 2.8.0) -- what if someday a newer Gson implementation would break this rule and break the backwards compatibility in a major release (let's say, hypothetic Gson 3) for whatever reason? This seems to be relevant to serializers/deserializers that use reflection to produce/consume JSON (for example, `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`). In order to guarantee the order, the most robust solution I could think of is direct write to output streams, say something like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    jsonWriter.setIndent("  ");
    jsonWriter.beginArray();
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    jsonWriter.name("New").value("Tester");
    jsonWriter.name("B").value("Tester");
    jsonWriter.name("A").value("Tester");
    jsonWriter.name("Test").value("Tester");
    jsonWriter.endObject();
    jsonWriter.endArray();
    jsonWriter.flush();
}
```

```java
[
  {
    "New": "Tester",
    "B": "Tester",
    "A": "Tester",
    "Test": "Tester"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yup, this works, but you're saying that it can be that in future updates of gson, you can't parse these json files anymore?

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx No, mot really. I just want to say that you keep in mind that JSON objects are unordered by design, and Gson `JsonObject` is not required to be ordered (and I believe it'll always be like that) - this is just how it's implemented for the write operation, and you still read in any order with any parser. :)

Comment: Okay so it doesn't really matter then, because I searched for this before I made this question and  almost all the sites said that there was no solution to this and now it seems so easy

Comment: Sorry, but it is not so easy. Introducing the semantic "order" is not the job ob the JSON library. So you should not rely on the particular implementation.

Answer (score 1):

JSON-Objects don't care about order of their attributes.

It may be that there are implementations of JSON-libraries that handle the input order. But I do not suggest to rely on the input order handled by any JSON-library as an JSON-Object is and should remain the assertion to be associative (key-value) and the keys are unordered.

So there is no intrinsic possibility to preserve the input order. The only way is to simulate it: You have to remember an order id and write your own ouputter that considers the order id during output.

Comment: Okay, it is quite a pity that we can't choose the order.

Comment: The point is that it is an associative datastructure. Order of object attributes is semantically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The way you define your model will impact the order of your serialisation to Json. Something like this should work :

```
public class MyModel {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string examine;
    public int combat;
    public List<Drop> drops;
    public int size;
}
```

Comment: If this works, then I would be very happy. I will see